# Ruby on Rails rendering object with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am following the book Agile Web Development with Rails 5.1 and am in Chapter 11 where I am trying to create a button that decrements the quantity of an item within my cart. I am trying to use ajax to solve this and calling the render method on the cart. I am getting the following error...

ActionView::Template::Error ('nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.):
    1: cart = document.getElementById("cart")
    2: cart.innerHTML = "<%= j render(@cart) %>"

the button that this ajax calls originates from is a partial if that changes anything. I am new to rails and am stuck.

decrement_quantity.js.coffee

```
cart = document.getElementById("cart")
cart.innerHTML = "<%= j render(@cart) %>"
```

_line_item.html.erb

```
<% if line_item== @current_item %>
<tr class="line-item-highlight">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
  <td id="quantity"><%= line_item.quantity %></td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td id="price" class="price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
  <td><%= button_to 'X', line_item, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  <td id="decrement_quantity"><%= button_to '-1', line_items_decrement_quantity_path(id: line_item.id), remote: true%></td>
</tr>
```

line_items_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :decrement_quantity]
.
.
.
  def decrement_quantity
    if @line_item.quantity > 1
      @line_item.quantity -= 1
      @line_item.save
    else
      @line_item.destroy
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_index_url, notice: 'Line item was successfully decremented.' }
      format.js {}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
.
.
.
```

routes.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  #get 'store/index'
  root 'store#index', as: 'store_index'

  post 'line_items/decrement_quantity'

  resources :products
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Im not sure if im missing something but the same ajax command from from a different button in a different view is working fine. Anyone to help guide me is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set `@cart`, which means your view is executing `"<%= j render(nil) %>"`.

Your controller only sets `@cart` via a before-action, which only runs before the `create` action:

```
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
```

If you want the `decrement_quantity` to push an `@cart` variable to the view, you need to either expand the `only:` option to include `[:create, :decrement_quantity]` (which may or may not work, you haven't included the contents of that method in your question) or explicitly set `@cart` inside the `decrement_quantity` action.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast response. This worked! Adding :decrement_quantity to the :set_cart before_action made the functionality work as intended. I guess since rails is stateless even though i already created the cart before it wasnt saved into the memory?